# appointment for life term

Tags: single-word-requests

One of the directors of a company is being appointed as chairman. He shall remain so for his life term.  Is there a particular term/word to describe a person holding a position or office for life?

Comment: i've heard it called a 'lifer'

Answer (score 1):

[***lifetime appointments***](http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/future_tense/2013/11/lifetime_appointments_don_t_make_sense_anymore.html)

***Example:***

There's actually nothing in the Constitution that explicitly promises federal judges "lifetime appointments."

Comment: Sorry @Rahul, you posted your answer just as I was typing. +1

Comment: @ArchContrarian: Happens more often. **_☺_**

Answer (score 0):

In academia, this is called being ***tenured***.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tenured

That term isn't normally used in business, but the meaning would be unambiguous if used of a company chairman.

Elsewhere, whole-life-term appointments can be shown by just prefixing "***life***", for example a "life peer" in the UK's House of Lords.

However, the most standard way of expressing this is a phrase, rather than a single word: ***lifetime appointment***